# jquery datable column search by clicking a link

Tags: javascript, datatables

This piece of javascript code is generated from coffee-script, which is very similar to the example code from [datatable](http://datatables.net/reference/api/column%28%29.search%28%29#Examples).

```
(function() {
  $(function() {
    var table;
    table = $('.table').dataTable({});
    return $("#filter-unread").click(function() {
      return table.columns('.status').search('unread').draw();
    });
  });

}).call(this);
```

But got an error when clicking the filtering unread button, how to fix it?

```
TypeError: table.columns is not a function
return table.columns('.status').search('unread').draw();
```

Comment: Isn't that just a typo? `DataTable()` should start with uppercased `D` instead of `dataTable()`

Comment: Yes, it is a typo. But the wired thing is lowercased `.dataTable()` still works if just doing an initialization.

Comment: Uppercase D is v1.10, lowercase is for v1.9.  AFAIK both will work when initilaising the table, but if you're using 1.10 API methods for searching, then you should really initialise with `Datatable`